# i need to find which one of the players is closer to the grid

Tags: java

so i did the function that will return me which one of the players is closer to the 2D grid(all this is inside a bigger grid) but i know for sure it's possible to me the function shorter and better. if  you can give give me some ideas on how

```
public static int getWhoIsCloser(
  int xFirstPlayer,
  int yFirstPlayer,
  int xSecondPlayer,
  int ySecondPlayer,
  int xCarpet,
  int yCarpet,
  int size) {

    size = size - 1;
    int xFirstPlayerProximity = 0;
    int yFirstPlayerProximity = 0;
    int xSecondPlayerProximity = 0;
    int ySecondPlayerProximity = 0;
    int firstPlayerResult;
    int secondPlayerResult;
    
    if (xFirstPlayer >= xCarpet && xFirstPlayer <= xCarpet + size) {
      yFirstPlayer -= (yCarpet + size);
      firstPlayerResult = Math.abs(yFirstPlayer);
    } else if (yFirstPlayer >= yCarpet && yFirstPlayer <= yCarpet + size) {
      xFirstPlayer -= (xCarpet + size);
      firstPlayerResult = Math.abs(xFirstPlayer);
    } else {
      if (xFirstPlayer < xCarpet && yFirstPlayer < yCarpet) {
        xFirstPlayerProximity = xFirstPlayer - xCarpet;
        yFirstPlayerProximity = yFirstPlayer - yCarpet;
      } else if (xFirstPlayer < xCarpet && yFirstPlayer > yCarpet) {
        xFirstPlayerProximity = xFirstPlayer - xCarpet;
        yFirstPlayerProximity = yFirstPlayer - (yCarpet + size);
      } else if (xFirstPlayer > xCarpet && yFirstPlayer < yCarpet) {
        xFirstPlayerProximity = xFirstPlayer - (xCarpet + size);
        yFirstPlayerProximity = yFirstPlayer - yCarpet;
      } else if (xFirstPlayer > xCarpet && yFirstPlayer > yCarpet) {
        xFirstPlayerProximity = xFirstPlayer - (xCarpet + size);
        yFirstPlayerProximity = yFirstPlayer - (yCarpet + size);
      }
      firstPlayerResult = Math.abs(xFirstPlayerProximity) + Math.abs(yFirstPlayerProximity);
    }
    if (xSecondPlayer >= xCarpet && xSecondPlayer <= xCarpet + size) {
      ySecondPlayer -= (yCarpet + size);
      secondPlayerResult = Math.abs(ySecondPlayer);
    } else if (ySecondPlayer >= yCarpet && ySecondPlayer <= yCarpet + size) {
      xSecondPlayer -= (xCarpet + size);
      secondPlayerResult = Math.abs(xSecondPlayer);
    } else {
      if (xSecondPlayer < xCarpet && ySecondPlayer < yCarpet) {
        xSecondPlayerProximity = xSecondPlayer - xCarpet;
        ySecondPlayerProximity = ySecondPlayer - (yCarpet);
      } else if (xSecondPlayer < xCarpet && ySecondPlayer > yCarpet) {
        xSecondPlayerProximity = xSecondPlayer - (xCarpet);
        ySecondPlayerProximity = ySecondPlayer - (yCarpet + size);
      } else if (xSecondPlayer > xCarpet && ySecondPlayer < yCarpet) {
        xSecondPlayerProximity = xSecondPlayer - (xCarpet + size);
        ySecondPlayerProximity = ySecondPlayer - yCarpet;
      } else if (xSecondPlayer > xCarpet && ySecondPlayer > yCarpet) {
        xSecondPlayerProximity = xSecondPlayer - (xCarpet + size);
        ySecondPlayerProximity = ySecondPlayer - (yCarpet + size);
      }
      secondPlayerResult = Math.abs(xSecondPlayerProximity) + Math.abs(ySecondPlayerProximity);
    }
    
    if (firstPlayerResult > secondPlayerResult) {
      return 2;
    } else if (firstPlayerResult < secondPlayerResult) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the function works and you are only looking to clean up the code, this question might be a better fit for [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: How are diagonals handled? If one player is (10, 5) away from the top right corner of the grid, is the distance 15 (one grid square at a time, horizonal and vertical only), 10 (same, but with diagonal moves) or sqrt(10^2+5^2) (direct path)?

Comment: no, that would be 15. i don't go diagonal